# How do I build a mobile(tablet) friendly version of my website?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I created website and it uses fluid layout CSS for most of the parts. I now want to make a tablet friendly look of this website.

This website should be viewable properly on Ipad. That's my only requirement.

How can I do this? Which are the development tools to speed me up for this?

**Edit:** Many people are give suggestion to use Jquery Mobile. Can I use that with my existing Asp.Net website? Do I need to change my whole existing CSS and also am I restricted to use those Jquery UI buttons only?

2nd and most important question is will this work with Asp.Net Vanilla. Say if I have a gridview on my page. Will Jquery mobile work?

Comment: See [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)

Comment: see this http://www.zurb.com/playground/responsive-tables or this http://www.zurb.com/article/1012/new-foundation-30-playground-release-off-

Comment: For asp.net gridview, check http://bit.ly/Sd4Aup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For device friendly website, you should use [Asp.net MVC4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4) and [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/). It has great [mobile features](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features)

> First you should read [Using HTML5 to Create Mobile Experiences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh975346.aspx) and [50 Responsive web examples](http://designmodo.com/responsive-design-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [CSS Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/). And [here is](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features) a useful article about ASP.NET MVC4 mobile features.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look into responsive CSS.  It uses device width and image scaling and good CSS definitions to scale the site to the device.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a framework for your responsive design.

e.g. [framelessgrid](http://framelessgrid.com/)